# HowTo use Windows Authentication with MSSQL 2008+Delphi 7+ADO but users would still enter their password?

Tags: delphi, windows-authentication, delphi-7

Does anybody know if it's possible to set up MSSQL 2008 to use Windows Authentication but users would still have to enter their windows password to log on (this would have to be accomplished by using Delphi 7+ADO)?

[Edit]: Just to clarify, the  sql-server and the clients are all within the same Windows Domain.

[Edit 2]: I don't want to write my own new LoginDialog but rather have SQL Server do that for me or let's say the DBConn control.

Kind Regards,
Reinhard

Comment: Isn't the whole idea behind Windows Authentication that it uses the current logon session without requiring the users to reenter their credentials?

Comment: @Jeroen: Why? I would have guessed that "windows authentication" would authenticate a user but why does it also provide a sort-of single sign on (I know that this was always the case but that doesn't mean I have to understand it though). Maybe I'm too paranoid but I do not like the idea of giving access to ppl only based on a mouse click :-) Why not give the choice if you want single-sign-on too?

Comment: @MarkRobinson: I don't see why such an application would be insecure? Users don't even know the difference between sql auth and windows auth and up until now within our old system they always had to provide username/password since only sql auth was used.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841978/change-username-programmatically-when-connecting-to-a-sql-server-using-windows-au

Comment: Windows logon is designed to make difficult to steal the password. Some user may not have a "password" at all, and logon using biometric devices or hardware tokens.

Comment: @pastacool: What you want to do is give the users a false sense of security. The idea of a windows domain is a strive for single sign-on and central administration. "Windows Authentication" helps with this: it enables you to defer the identification logic to Windows. Microsoft has many more resources of keeping this process safe than you have (especially when you write your own login dialog: it makes your app much more vulnerable to 'sniffing'). The only reason for developing your own login is for users to impersonate another user: Scott W presented the right link for that.

--jeroen

Comment: @Jeroen: That's all correct but I didn't say I want to write my own LoginDialog but I wanted to have MSSQL to be set up to provide that.
Anyways, It looks like my question can only be answered with a plain "NO, this can't be done". The question now is, how do I close my question since, until now, no one said it's not possible but just told me it would be insecure?

Comment: I would suggest that the question should not be closed/deleted.  It may be valuable for someone else in the future to find this discussion.

Comment: @pastacool: indeed the answer is NO; the SQL Server client does not provide a UI, it provides a connection layer. Your app is for the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this, you could prompt the user to (re-)enter credentials and then verify and handle appropriately based on success/failure.  To do this, you are looking for the [`LogonUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  At this point, you could even allow a user to log into the database using credentials other than those used to log into the computer by using the [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841978/change-username-programmatically-when-connecting-to-a-sql-server-using-windows-au/1842172#1842172).

Comment: Thanks for the link, maybe I can use it somehow

Comment: Since the direct answer to my question is "NO, SQL Server cannot be set up that way" I will go ahead with what you suggest in yours because this way I can kind of rebuild a Linux like "SUDO" where I don't want to impersonate someone else but force the user to re-enter his password.

Answer (score 2):

It would be rather insecure and probably reduce trust in your app if you made users enter their domain user and password again, in your app. As Jeroen mentions above, the whole idea of using windows auth is that the existing user session is used!

> @MarkRobinson: I don't see why such an
>   application would be insecure? Users
>   don't even know the difference between
>   sql auth and windows auth and up until
>   now within our old system they always
>   had to provide username/password since
>   only sql auth was used

Users don't know the difference so show them the way - if they've logged into their domain account, and by some mechanism of your software they are allowed to use your application, then by all means let them in with a click - show a splash screen that makes them aware you are "Autologging them in with their domain credentials..." or similar, that way you have made them aware that you're saving them time.

It would be insecure for the simple fact that you are adding a step that isn't required, as the windows auth login removes this very issue.

Edit1:

Re-Reading the original question, I can see that the op just wants to pop the default windows login prompt to ensure the security.

I would recommend either:

1. Ensure there is a screensaver, with a pertinent timeout that will force a relogin
2. Use LockWorkStation to force a relogin event (perhaps show a message first, along the lines of "for security, your workstation will be locked to ensure you are who you say you are"

Comment: I agree that it would be "convenient" to not have to enter the password again but again why would this be insecure. If that would be the case then why is SUDO used in Linux so much? Although a user is already logged on with his windows credentials I still want him to enter his password again to ADD security so in case he/she just moves for a short period of time from their desk (I know they "should" lock their screen but that's not how reality looks like) someone else could run this application under someone else's credentials.

Comment: @pastacool SUDO is a built in OS command, same as RUNAS under windows, which I would assume as secure (as it would have been tested more), plus I'm sure that the people who run SUDO and RUNAS know they are going to login as someone else and enter their windows credentials.

Good idea on the screen saver lock, I'd rather add code that will pop the screen saver after 5 minutes inactivity then ask for a password on resume = more secure :D

Comment: @Mark: So if you read my question you will see that I wanted to know HOW I could set up MSSQL to accomplish that and not really by implementing my own SUDO like command. That, I will agree, would be less secure.

Comment: Aah, I get you now - I just read your recent edit and you just wanted to pop the standard windows login prompt when your app starts to force reauthentication... I don't think it can, but ensuring there is a screen saver with a timeout that forces a relogin can be done through code (just remember to restore the initial values on exit) <- the answer :D

Comment: @Mark: that's exactly what I wanted - should have said that in the question but if you ask for something you're so "blind" because to you everything is clear! Any idea how to handle my question now as, like "Scott W" suggested to not close/delete so someone else can at least find this discussion about it, but NOT let it hanging unanswered?

Comment: @pastacool Can you read? I offered two answers above - you're so blind because to you everything is clear. No need to get offensive btw, I'm only trying to help - take advice and learn from it rather than become offensive like a petulant child.

Comment: @mark: sorry, again a misunderstanding. please replace you/you're with I/me

Comment: @pastacool - sorry, i did indeed misread your last comment, I apologise for the petulant child remark... my bad...

Comment: @mark: +1 and apology accepted - I could have been clearer in the beginning. this thought me again that I shouldn't "write" like I would "talk" to someone

Answer (score 1):

From the page Scott W linked to, there is a good link to [How to validate user credentials on Microsoft operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180548). In particular, they go into a little bit of detail about the security aspect:

> **Note** Collecting user credentials from a User-mode application can be annoying to the users and can provide a possible security hole in the enterprise computing environment. The Unified Logon requirement (a requirement that the user should only be required to type their credentials one time at the CTRL+ALT+DEL screen), was added to the Microsoft BackOffice logo requirements for these very reasons. It is important to make sure that you really need to gather credentials and that some other method of client/server validation is not more appropriate. Consult the security documentation in the Platform SDK for more information on impersonation and programming secured servers.